# Playlist is not getting cleared in embed vlc media player using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, vlc

Trying to incorporate online radio streaming to one of my client .

Playlist is not getting cleared and not able to play next pointed URL.

### Below is the html code for the same. Let me know where I am doing the mistake

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function play_vlc(ip) {
var d=document.getElementById('vlc').playlist;

d.stop();
d.items.clear();
d.add(ip);

//document.getElementById('vlc').target=ip;
d.next();
d.play();
console.log("Playing "+ip);

}
</script>
<body>
<embed id="vlc" type="application/x-vlc-plugin" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" >
<a href="#" id="radio1">Radio City 91.1</a><hr>
<a href="#" id="radio2">Radio City Freedom</a><hr>
<a href="#" id="radio3">Desi Music Mix</a><hr>
<a href="#" id="radio4">Amsterdam Trance Radio</a><hr>
<a href="#" id="radio5">Classic Hard Rock </a><br>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ipaddr=new Array("http://208.115.222.205:9998/","http://199.19.106.253:9962/","http://216.240.130.150:8014/","http://205.164.62.13:7700/","http://176.31.235.147:8000/");

function playradio(ip){
play_vlc(ip);
//alert(ip);    
}
for(i=1;i<6;i++){
var j=ipaddr[i-1];  
console.log(j);
document.getElementById('radio'+i).ind=j;
document.getElementById('radio'+i).onclick=function () {
    playradio(this.ind);
    };
}
</script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Off topic: Instead of creating an anonymous function for each `document.getElementById('radio'+i).onclick`, you should store a single function into a variable before the loop, and in the loop use that variable.

Comment: Above snippet is only for testing purpose . Implementation is entirely different from the above . Anyways thanks :)

Comment: Note that when this method returns, playlist may not have been entirely been cleared as this operation is performed asynchronously; use the count property to verify/wait until the playlist is empty.http://wiki.videolan.org/JavaScript_API#Playlist_items_object